# Javascript Calendar - Jquery already used on the site

Tags: jquery, calendar

A client uses yahoo calendars for his business. 
He is asking me to create a calendar to show the event updates he makes on Yahoo.

I am using Jquery on the site already and would prefer to use it for this as well if possible.

I see there is datepicker and such, but this needs to just display the Yahoo or Google (he said he would be open to switching his calendar services) calendar on his site.

Thanks.

-Brian

Comment: So basically you want to use the jquery datepicker and show Yahoo or Google on the calendar?

Answer (score 1):

Your client will have to switch to Google Calendar since Yahoo Calendar doesn't provide a way to embed a calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you just wish to embed his Yahoo/Google calendar on a web page? If so, why not just do so using an iframe?

[This article](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=41207) walks you through embedding a Google calendar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [google calendar gadget](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/calendar_gadgets.html).

Check out this links as well:

- [Google Embeddable Calendar Helper](http://www.google.com/calendar/embedhelper)
- [About Google Calendar](http://www.google.com/googlecalendar/event_publisher_guide.html)